# how to listen to the original observable after it is flatmaped to a new observable?

Tags: android, rx-java2

```
public Observable<Void> onFabClicked() {
    return RxView.clicks(a_button);
}

{ 
    view.onOutBoundBtClicked() 
        .observeOn(computationScheduler) 
        .map(new Func1<Void, ViewModelAction>() {
              @Override public ViewModelAction call(Void aVoid) { 
                    return new OutboundInputFieldTappedAction(); 
              } 
        }).mergeWith(view.onFabClicked().flatMap(new Func1<Void, Observable<ListOfResult>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<ListOfResult> call(Void avoid) {
                    return listRepository.getListResult("UK",
                                    "en-GB",
                                    ).toObservable();
                }
            }).map(new Func1<ListOfResult, ViewViewModelAction>() {
                @Override
                public ViewViewModelAction call(ListOfResult ListOfResult) {

                    return new ListOfResultsReceivedAction(ListOfResult);
                }
            }))
    .mergeWith(view.onFabClicked()
    .observeOn(computationScheduler)
    .map(new Func1<Void, ViewModelAction>() {
                @Override
                public ViewModelAction call(Void aVoid) {
                    return new SearchPanelAnimationAction();
                }
            }))
```

I have an observable1 which is come from RxView.clicks(a_button), how can I create another observable2 from this click observable1, then emit observable1 and observable2 to a same subscriber? I tried flatmap that convert observable1 to ovservable2 but then observalbe1 is never heard, the code is

```
{
    view.onOutBoundBtClicked().observeOn(computationScheduler).map(new Func1() {
        @Override
        public ViewModelAction call(Void aVoid) {
            return new OutboundInputFieldTappedAction();
        }
    }).mergeWith.
```

, and why I always return an XXXAction is that I will change some fields in the viewModel, and I will use

```
    .withLatestFrom(viewModels, new Func2() {
    @Override
    public ActivityViewModel call(ViewModelAction action, ActivityViewModel activityViewModel) {
        return action.modifyViewModel(activityViewModel);
    }
```

so when ever something changed in the viewmodel I will get an event emitted and do some thing upon it, thanks, guys.

Comment: `I tried flatmap that convert observable1 to ovservable2 but it doesn't work` add code (see [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: `Describe the problem. "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement. Tell us what the expected behavior should be. Tell us what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Put a brief summary of the problem in the title of your question.`

Comment: thanks for the comments, I added some code snippet, as you can see, I still want to consume the onFabClicked observable after flatmap it, how can I achieve it. or any workaround, thanks!

Comment: not to be splitting hairs but what is `view.onFabClicked()`? and what is before `.mergeWith`?

Comment: thanks, it is{ return RxView.clicks(a_button) ;} so its an observable , and before .mergeWith is basicly some other similar onclicks ,

Comment: `and before .mergeWith is basicly some other similar onclicks ` that sounds important ya know -_-

Comment: it's {   view.onOutBoundBtClicked()
                .observeOn(computationScheduler)
                .map(new Func1<Void, ViewModelAction>() {
                    @Override
                    public ViewModelAction call(Void aVoid) {
                        return new OutboundInputFieldTappedAction();
                    }
                }).mergeWith...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an observable field that is shared, and expose that instead of returning `RxView.clicks()` directly.

```
Observable<Void> fabClicks;

public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    ...

    fabClicks = RxView.clicks(a_button).share();
}

public Observable<Void> onFabClicked() {
    return fabClicks;
}
```